# Strange data frame structure

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm fairly new to R and have a data frame with entries I don't quit understand. When looking at the df it simply contains numbers, but when looking at the structure they are like this: `0` = 1424. How can I just keep the numbers? Does anyone know why that might be - maybe because the df was formerly a list?

Here's some of the data frame:

```
structure(list(a = structure(c(`0` = 1424, `1` = 106, 
`2` = 39, `3` = 25, `4` = 21, `5` = 4), class = "table"), b = structure(c(`0` = 1424, 
`1` = 95, `2` = 51, `3` = 12, `4` = 11, `5` = 9), class = "table"), 
    c = structure(c(`0` = 1473, `1` = 131, `2` = 46, 
    `3` = 32, `4` = 6, `5` = 24), class = "table"), d = structure(c(`0` = 1473, 
    `1` = 108, `2` = 27, `3` = 21, `4` = 11, `5` = 16), class = "table"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

I was trying to display the data like this but then it displayed c(`0` = 1424) in all the grids.

```
library(tidyverse)
library()

df %>%
  htmlTable()
```

Any hints are much appreciated

Comment: What would be the expected output here?

Comment: Something like this? `dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(l[-length(l)], as.vector))`?

Comment: This dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(l, as.vector)) basically does what I want, thanks! Do you have an idea as to why my data frame might be like that?

Comment: Not really, no. It looks a weirdly formatted version of the output of the `dput` function. Actually, the elements are probably frequency table of numbers (0 to 5), over multiple columns/vectors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your dataframe is in fact a list consisting of uneven vectors.
To convert it to a dataframe I would use :

```
df <- structure(list(a = structure(c(`0` = 1424, `1` = 106, 
                                   `2` = 39, `3` = 25, `4` = 21, `5` = 4), class = "table"),
                     b = structure(c(`0` = 1424,`1` = 95, `2` = 51, `3` = 12,
                                    `4` = 11, `5` = 9), class = "table"), 
                     c = structure(c(`0` = 1473, `1` = 131, `2` = 46, 
                                   `3` = 32, `4` = 6, `5` = 24), class = "table"),
                     d = structure(c(`0` = 1473,`1` = 108, `2` = 27, `3` = 21, `4` = 11,
                         `5` = 16), class = "table"),
                     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))

unlisted_df <- as.data.frame(sapply(df, '[', seq(max(sapply(df, length)))))
```

This converts your list to a dataframe that looks like this with NA where your vectors are uneven.

```
a    b    c    d      class
1424 1424 1473 1473   tbl_df
106   95  131  108    tbl
39   51   46   27     data.frame
25   12   32   21     <NA>
21   11    6   11     <NA>
4    9    24   16     <NA>
```